# Get multiple attributes from servlet/s to same JSP

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, refresh, dispatcher

I have a problem getting multiple attributes in a JSP page (one jsp-page) from two different servlets. I'm getting an exception because when the JSP loads, both of the request.getAttribute() are executed, and one of them have not yet been "sent" from the servlet.

I first send this from the first servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("user", user);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("success.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

This is how i get it from the JSP-file:

```
user = (User) request.getAttribute("user");
You are logged in as <%= user.getUsername() %>.
```

Now from the other servlet I send this:

```
request.setAttribute("convertedValue", convertedValue);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("success.jsp");
dispatcher.include(request, response);
```

And get this in the JSP:

```
double value = (Double) request.getAttribute("convertedValue");
```

The problem is that I can't have it like this because I cannot get something that's "not there yet". I've tried with if-statements like if(getAttribute!=null) but it's not so good.

Maybe updating a part of the JSP page would work but I don't know how. I'm not so familiar with AJAX..

I really hope you guys can help me out with this!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting to the `request`,you can set user object to the session as below  so it won't be vanished for every new request and  avaliable with in the session .

like

```
req.getSession().setAttribute("user",user);
```

otherwise it wont be possible to share between the requests .

Thanks .

*I hope I understood your question in right way.*